Ubuntu 24.04 PXE UEFI IPv4 boot
I have successfully configured grubx64.efi, and is able to launch
grub.cfg menu that will then load casper/vmlinuz and casper/initrd from the Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop AMD64.iso image.
set casper_path='iso/ubuntu-24-04-iso_extrct/'
set config='http://192.168.60.1/pxe-cloud/u24-04/'
set config_user_data='http://192.168.60.1/pxe-cloud/u24-04/user-data'
set ubuntu_iso_url='http://192.168.60.1/pxe-cloud/u24-04/ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
echo 'Loading kernel vmlinux using '
echo ${ubuntu_iso_url}
echo '...'
#echo 'Loading kernel Ubuntu 24.04 vmlinux using url ISO method ...'
linux ${casper_path}casper/vmlinuz ip=dhcp cloud-config-url=${config_user_data} url=${ubuntu_iso_url} autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=${config} root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200n8
initrd ${casper_path}casper/initrd

Everything works fine, and the Ubuntu24.04 was loaded until at the end...
it appears that an infinite session-[session id].scope was created.
The log in prompt was not there.
Infinite systemctl status session-[session id].scope created
On the same setup, Ubuntu22.04 ISO and the corresponding casper/vmlinuz and casper/initrd works perfectly, and it ends at the log in prompt. I could then log in as ubuntu user.
Successful Boot for Ubuntu22.04
I am not familiar with PXE-boot, but could anyone advise how this can be resolved ?enter image description here

Are you trying to load a live system? or an ISO image to then install a live system?

I wanted to get into the ubuntu login prompt like what I have using Ubuntu 22.04 PXE boot.
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ubuntu ttyS0
ubuntu login: ubuntu
Password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-25-generic x86_64)

That does not answer the question, are you trying to load a live environment, that you will then use like a normal system (either as persistent storage or non-persistent) or are you trying to load an image, to then install Ubuntu on drives?

Loading a live environment from casper, then install Ubuntu on drives.

I have changed to ubuntu-24.04-live-server-amd64.iso from ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso and everything works fine with nocloud.

Just a note for the benefit of other users. The original grub as shown above actually works for Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop AMD64 iso. Most importantly, the desktop iso casper expects to boot on a system with display output to load gnome desktop properly. I was on a headless system, hence  Infinite systemctl status session-[session id].scope was created.
The grub settings works on system that has display output such as Displayport or HDMI.

User on headless should add in "single" to prevent desktop from loading.
console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200n8 single
